# Android - How an AlertDialog injected with spinner can be closed when touched outer view?

Tags: android, dialog, touch, spinner

Basically what I want to do is closing Spinner's Dialog Box and the Customized Dialog I've created when clicked outside of those boxes. Anyone knows how to handle these?

**dialog.xml, My Spinner's xml, MakeandShowDialogBox function below :**

**dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/scheduleTable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ></TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Spinner XML**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/strDepartmentNames"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
```

**makeAndShowDialogBox**

```
private void makeAndShowDialogBox() {

    AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    // Set three option buttons
    myDialogBox.setPositiveButton("Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });

    myDialogBox.setView(dialogView);
    myDialogBox.create();
    myDialogBox.show();
}
```

Comment: same problem for spinner...!! have you solution now?

Answer (score 5):

you just add this option in your dialog

`myDialogBox.setCancelable(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call this method `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`.

```
myDialogBox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Afaik It should work.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not able to call a method like that with a View Object. So it does not work for one part of it, Spinner one is a mystery as well.

Comment: @Mack Did you try on `myDialogBox` this ?

Comment: Only `Cancellable` comes out of both.