# How to dismiss the spinner with click on outside of the dialog?

Tags: android

How to dismiss the dialog spinner with click on outside of the dialog?
I try it in nexus 7(2013) and I can click on outside of the dialog spinner to dismiss it without adding any code in fragment but not work in Samsung Tablet , so I want to know how to dismiss it or something I miss to add.

and I found some link about this  [Android - How an AlertDialog injected with spinner can be closed when touched outer view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961287/alertdialog-and-spinner-dialog-close-when-touched-outside-how).
But there is no setCancelable(true) method of Object - Spinner.

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dialog_spinner"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="38ip"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
         />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

if (!hasFocus) v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have setCancelable method nor setCanceledOnTouchOutside use this function:

```
 public static void clickOutSideSpinner(View view)
        {
            // Configure touch listener for all views except edittext,Button and Spinner
            if (!(view instanceof EditText)
                 &&!(view instanceof Button)  
                 &&!(view instanceof Spinner))
            {
                view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        //here you close your dialog spinner

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            //runs through all the children views .
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
                    closeSlidingDrawerOnTouch(innerView);
                }
            }
        }
```

In onCreate call your function and pass layout :

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView  textviw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviw1);
            Spinner  spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            Button  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            //change to other layout if you use other
            LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

            clickOutSideSpinner(layout1);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog.Builder have setCancelable(boolean cancelable) method, you need to pass true to dismiss the dialog on you clicking outside the dialog.

Ensure that your dialog containing the spinner has cancelable property set as true

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html
for this property description.

Comment: This is Spinner. In Spinner object, there is no setCancelable(boolean cancelable) method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html